# CSS Span Grid Resizing?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I have 12 circles that I've set up in a CSS grid, all the same size, all even etc (I've created a basic fiddle and added the code below). This grid is inside a bootstrap container with flex, along with some other content.
The problem: When I resize the page, the other elements I have on the page in other grids and flex-box, resize just fine. However these circles all stay the exact same size and don't alter with the rest of the content. They do move around the container, but don't resize. I've tried wrapping things, altering the #circle parent, applying min and max widths, all sorts! So this is really bugging me now.
I know I've used spans to achieve this and I'm guessing thats where my problem lies (unless it's because it's in the flex container). Is there any way of moving forward with this method?

Thank you very much!

html:

```
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div id="circle">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#circle {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 35px 35px 35px;
  grid-template-rows: 35px 35px 35px 35px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  
}

#circle span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cthjbdsn/17/#&togetherjs=3tlSpRSn5c

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tLzdm4aw/2/) what you would like to have ?

I have:

1. changed the grid row and column size from `35px` to `1fr` to make the cells adapt to their container.
2. changed the span size from `2em` to `100%` to make them adapt to their cells.
3. added a size to the container (here `calc(3 / 4 * 100vh)` x `100vh`), but you can change that by putting your container somewhere and giving it the appropriate size. The circles will resize according to its size.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#circle {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: calc(3 / 4 * 100vh);
}

#circle span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="circle">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: That's sort of it.. They are resizing now, however they also squish and don't remain as circles. I need them to be a set of circles that resizes similar to how text does. It just gets bigger or smaller depending on resizing. Thank you though, I will take your suggestions and see if I can work from there :)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd fixed it using the fr's and the calc, but it was still a bit squiffy (aha).

I have though found something that uses bottom padding and finally achieved what I've set out to do, as follows:

css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#circle {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#circle span {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5vw;
  height: 5vw;
  padding-bottom: 0vw;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```